# Samsung Email on S10+ only showing unread emails

Tags: samsung, email, samsung-email

Samsung Email on S10+ only shows unread emails. I see some (but not all) of the new emails, but as soon as I read them, they disappear.  As a result, it always looks like I have no emails, even though there are hundreds of read emails visible on other machines (like a PC using a web browser).  I cannot scroll down through previous emails to find a message.  Using Microsoft 365 email services and Samsung Email.  I cannot find any way to configure this app.

Comment: According to the screenshots from [the Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.samsung.android.email.provider), there should be a navigation drawer on the left that can be opened by either swiping the edge of the screen or pressing the 3-horizontal lines on the top-left. Have you tried it?

Comment: Thanks, Andrew!  When I swipe the left edge of the screen right, all I get is a list of icons (probably some kind of quick launch gimmick).  When I am looking at the Inbox, there is a 3-horizontal-lines thingy, but all that gets me is a list of folders.  I looked at the Play Store and could not find a screen shot that showed a navigation drawer.  Which screen shot were you referring to?

Comment: I just tried Blue Mail, and it, too, only shows a subset of the emails that I am receiving.  Maybe there is an email server setting that I need to tweak.  Puzzling.

Comment: [This one is the navigation drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQ3sml.png), showing "Inbox" and "Unread". I thought the issue was it's on "Unread" folder, but considering that after using 3rd-party email apps it's still the same, then perhaps it's a server setting. I just did a quick search "microsoft 365 email delete after read" and one of the results is from [Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/outlook-email-on-phone-just-started-automatically/c5e69e4b-b3a6-4927-af67-814f3c6b3d50) where it mentioned the "Leave a copy of the messages on server" settings.

Comment: Now, I want to stop the Samsung Email app from working with my email, but I can't find any way to tell it to stop.  If this app is configurable, all of the settings are hidden

Comment: I finally found the configuration forms, but not in the app at all, which is very confusing.  I disabled Samsung Email.  I believe that some messages were missing from my main email display (on my desktop).  The whole thing became too unreliable and dangerous for me to continue using.